# javascript buttons to toggle font from bold to original

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a button where A button for setting the text in the text area to bold, and unsetting it to its previous state. This should be the same button.

```js
function toggleBold() {
  var bold = true
  if (bold = ture) {
    document.getElementById("entertext").
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleBold">BOLD</button>


<form>
  Enter Text:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="your text" id="entertext">
</form>
```

Comment: typo here: `if(bold = ture){`

Comment: more than a typo. `if (bold)` or  `if (bold==true)` - and either are useless unless you move the `var bold` outside the function and do `bold=!bold` inside the function

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205680/bold-and-unbold-button-for-text-in-a-form-box/42206083#42206083

Comment: @mplungjan that was at first sight. in fact this script is too "rear".

Comment: What does "too rear" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jquery

Form

```
<button class="toggleBold">BOLD</button>
<form>
  Enter Text:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="your text" id="entertext">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(".toggleBold").click(function() {
   document.getElementById("entertext").classList.toggle("bold");
});
```

Css

```
 .bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: up  for using Jquery (for the memes)

Comment: First, JQuery is overkill for this. Second, you actually aren't using JQuery to do the toggle. You are only using it to bind the button. Third, JQuery wasn't tagged in the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  OP did not mention anything in specific.. It doesnt mean that we cant do it that way and not a reason to downvote

Comment: Adding JQuery for such a trivial task is overkill and not a good suggestion. To add a whole library just to get a DOM reference and bind it to a click event is just plain ridiculous.

Comment: The really funny thing about your answer is that, not only are you not using JQuery to actually solve the problem, but you are using it to get one DOM reference, but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting up a class for bold and then toggling that class on the text element.

Also, you should not use HTML event attributes to bind your DOM objects to event handlers because:

- They create spaghetti code that is harder to read and leads to code
  duplication.
- They add global wrapper functions around your supplied function that
  alter the `this` binding within the event handling function.
- They don't follow the **[W3C DOM Event](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#methods-1)** standard.

You should do all the event binding in JavaScript and use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

```js
// Get DOM element references
var btn = document.getElementById("btnToggleBold");
var txt = document.getElementById("txtInput");

// Wire the button's click event up to a toggle function
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Toggle the bold class on the text element
  txt.classList.toggle("bold");
});
```

```css
/* This class will be toggled via a button click */
.bold {font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <button id="btnToggleBold">BOLD</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Enter Text:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This does the same as the link I gave in the comment to this question

Comment: The end result is the same, but my answer does not use event properties (as yours does) and my answer explains why addEventListener should be used instead of event properties or HTML event attributes.

Comment: I prefer something that works in all browsers since the dawn of time. e.g. element.onclick - not inline attributes. Alternatively use jQuery to not have to normalise the addEventListener

Comment: So, you believe in not following standards and you prefer a less robust event handling model. You have to go back to IE 8 for .addEventListener to not work. That is very much a minority of users. Also, as I said, adding an extra HTTP call and downloading a whole library for such a trivial task is unwarranted.

Comment: We have 10% IE8 users and no. Use jQuery if you have it anyway

Comment: If you are using JQuery anyway, then sure, use it. But, if not, you can write a simple cross-browser solution without the added overhead of JQuery. Advising to use JQuery on this is just wrong. Also, using event properties does not follow standards (how would you register a second event handler for the same event?) and should not be recommended.

Comment: I never advise jQuery for simple things. I do however use onclick and onchange in script when I do not need multiple    functions on the same event. It is called pragmatism. I have written JS since 1996 and cannot remember when I ever needed two event handlers for the same event

Comment: Actually, it's called "not-scalable" and inadvisable and certainly not advice you should be giving to others.

Comment: As with so many things in programming (and life), just because you haven't done it, doesn't mean that others won't. I too have have been working with JS since the early 90's and often need to wire up multiple event handlers to single DOM objects. Designing code that is scalable and follows standards is always the right thing to do unless we are talking about working on legacy systems. I also have coding habits that I know aren't the best, but I know enough not to suggest those to others.

Comment: So you would use browser detection a few years ago to decide on addEventListener support? I consider that worse than using on..

Comment: No, I would have used "feature detection", not "browser detection". They are not the same thing and is, in fact, how JQuery implements cross-browser support.